# How to tell the compiler to throw errors for the variables that are not declared as "volatile" but used within an interrupt handler?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, static-analysis, volatile

We need to declare the variables that are not meant to be enregistered or optimized as `volatile` if they are only modified within an external event (within an interrupt in embedded domain).

```
uint8_t var1; 
volatile uint8_t var2, var3;

void my_interrupt_handler(){
  var1++; 
  var2++; 
  var3++; 
}
```

How can I tell the compiler to throw such an error upon compilation:

```
ERROR: var1 is referenced in an external event section. It must be declared as volatile.
```

I'm using GCC.

Comment: I'm not sure any compiler or linter would have such a warning, although if some static analysis tools have user-defined hooks you might be able to set one up.  If you're hoping for options for any specific compiler, you'd better say which one you're using, though!  e.g. GCC and Clang have different warnings that can be enabled.

Comment: There are some cases where that wouldn't be an error, e.g. a non-volatile global that's *only* used by ISR code, not accessed from anywhere else.  (So it could be `static` within the ISR function, except maybe a couple different functions called from `my_interrupt_handler` all want to use it.)  If your coding practices don't do that, great, then you can maybe detect this without false positives, if some static analysis tool has a way to know which functions are interrupt handlers.  Maybe your real code uses `__attribute__((interrupt))`, or you give it a list of ISR function names?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend not using the word "cached" to describe the difference between volatile and non-volatile.  `volatile` doesn't bypass CPU cache (and doesn't need to, even on multicore systems), it only stops compilers from keeping the value in registers.  The word for that in compiler jargon is "enregistering".  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enregister .  It's already covered by "not optimized", i.e. a load or store has to happen in asm for every access to the C variable in the abstract machine.

Comment: I would also advice against using _"the compiler throws"_ ... It rarely does, but when it does, everyone is on their toes. I have only seen ICEs, no throws. I don't even think _throws_ exists.

Comment: You might instead simply put the interrupt function in a separate file, and not include the headers that declare other global variables.

Comment: @o11c I didn't quite understand your technique. Wouldn't the compiler enregister the variables that are declared in another file? What's your catch point?

Comment: If non-`volatile` global variables aren't even declared, an ISR that attempts to use them won't compile at all.  But @o11c's idea would mean grouping variables to header files depending on whether or not any interrupt handler touches them, rather than keeping related variables together.  If that gets clunky, perhaps a `#ifndef VOLATILE_VARS_ONLY` could guard the other globals.  Compilations units with ISRs would have to `#define VOLATILE_VARS_ONLY` before #include of other headers, so it's not foolproof and more noisy.

Comment: Aside: declaring variables as `volatile` is not the panacea you might think. There are [all kinds of subtleties to consider](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/28).

Comment: @pmacfarlane I read most of the document and I'll read all of them ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to make volatile access very explicit in the code by naming volatile variables specially.

This way, an interrupt handler function can "require" a variable to be volatile and an error will be raised if that was missing in the declaration.

E.g.:

```
#define VOLATILE_VAR(x) volatile_##x

uint8_t var1; 
volatile uint8_t VOLATILE_VAR(var2), VOLATILE_VAR(var3);

void my_interrupt_handler(){
  VOLATILE_VAR(var1)++; 
  VOLATILE_VAR(var2)++; 
  VOLATILE_VAR(var3)++; 
}
```

The compiler will now raise an error because `var1` is not a "`VOLATILE_VAR`".

Of course, this is not 100% fool-proof since it is possible to declare a "`VOLATILE_VAR`" without actually making it `volatile`, but that should stand out quite clearly and it should be easy to search for all lines in header files containing `VOLATILE_VAR`, but not `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some occasions where lack of *decideability* means that human intervention is the most optimal option.

A human reviewer can quickly check that appropriate variables are declared as `volatile` and other appropriate (local) variables are declared as `static`.

I'd also echo the suggest elsewhere that the interrupt handlers (and their volatile variables) are contained in a separate translation unit, so limit the scope of such manual review.

Hopefully, your interrupt handlers are quite small, so this should not be onerous, and your other compilation checks and static analysis will detect your other problems.

Despite the enhanced capabilities of tools, manual review is still a valid tool in the box.